# php 5.5 sorting array by value and subvalue

Tags: php, sorting

I have a working sorting code in PHP 7

```
usort($ferr, function($a, $b) {
    $retval = $b['value'] <=> $a['value'];
    if($retval == 0) {
        $retval = $b['subvalue'] <=> $a['subvalue'];    
    }
    return $retval;
});
```

but `PHP 5.5` doesn't support the `<=>` operator. It only supports `-` operator, which doesn't work in this case. How can it be done in `PHP 5.5` ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: The spaceship operator could be shorthand for `$a == $b?0:($a<$b?-1:1)` (or something like that)

Comment: Well, the <=> operator (the spaceship operator) gives combined comparison:

Return 0 if values on either side are equal
Return 1 if value on the left is greater
Return -1 if the value on the right is greater

So you'll need to write your code to that effect, we cannot do it for you - you know what you need to do.

Comment: Also PHP 5.5 does not *only* support the `-` operator.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/E4Bor

Comment: @Stuart now it's easy thanks!

Comment: *"It only supports - operator, which doesn't work in this case"* -- Why it doesn't work? If `$a['value']` and `$b['value']` are numbers then the subtraction produces the same result (in this context) as the `<=>` operator. If they are strings then the function [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) is the way to go. For other data types, I don't think `<=>` could help you either.

Comment: The first value are decimal number (between 0-5) the second integers. When I use only the - operator a get strange results. First is the one with highest subvalue and then it seems like a random mix.. @axiac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own function for the spaceship `<=>` operator, like this:

```
function spaceship($a, $b) {
    return $a < $b ? -1 : ($a > $b ? 1 : 0);
}

usort($ferr, function ($a, $b) {
    $retval = spaceship($b['value'], $a['value']);

    if ($retval == 0) {
        $retval = spaceship($b['subvalue'], $a['subvalue']);
    }

    return $retval;
});
```